# Condition variables and shared memory

Tags: c, mutex, shared-memory, condition-variable

I tried to use condition variable (with mutex) inside shared memory to synchronize parent and child after exec. Everything seems to be fine, the child and parent are synchronized. But at random point of the execution, I receive every time the error " Invalid argument " on pthread_cond_wait function.

#### File `test1.c`

The code below is the parent that creates mutex, cond variable (inside shared memory) and another block of shared memory for data, and then try to share data with the child.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>     

#define PNUM 17500
#define PLENGHT 60
#define MAXLINE 4096


void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...);
void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...);
static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap);

int main (int argc , char *argv[]){

    /* creating new mutex inside shared memory area */
    void *shmem_mu_ptr;             /* pointer to mutex shared memory */         
    pthread_mutex_t *mu;            /* pointer to mutex */
    int shmem_mu_id;                /* shared memory mutex id */        
    int mu_err;
    size_t size = sizeof(pthread_mutex_t);  /* shared m. mutex size (size was already declared )*/
    char packet[PLENGHT];

    for(int i = 0; i < PLENGHT; i++) packet[i] = 'a';

    /* getting shared m. id for mutex*/
    if ( (shmem_mu_id =  shmget((key_t)1111, size , 0666 | IPC_CREAT )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for mutex */
    if ((shmem_mu_ptr = shmat(shmem_mu_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make mu, that expects a memory area made like pthread_mutex_t , to point the shared memory. */
    mu = (pthread_mutex_t *)shmem_mu_ptr;

    /* initialize the attribute to prepare mutex to be placed in shared memory */
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr,PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    /* initialize mutex */
    pthread_mutex_init(mu,&attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);


    /* creating new condition variable inside shared memory area */
    void *shmem_cond_ptr;           /* pointer to cond shared memory */
    int shmem_cond_id;              /* shared memory cond id */     
    pthread_cond_t *cond;
    size = sizeof(pthread_cond_t);  /* shared m. cond size (size was already declared )*/

    /* getting shared m. id for cond*/
    if ( (shmem_cond_id =  shmget((key_t)2222, size , 0666 | IPC_CREAT )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for cond */
    if ((shmem_cond_ptr = shmat(shmem_cond_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make cond, that expects a memory area made like pthread_cond_t , to point the shared memory. */
    cond = (pthread_cond_t *)shmem_cond_ptr;


    /* * initialize the attribute to prepare cond to be placed in shared memory */
    pthread_condattr_t attrcond;
    pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    /* Initialize condition. */
    pthread_cond_init(cond, &attrcond);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);

    /* Clean up. */
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond); 


    /* creating new shared memory area to share only PLENGHT (60) byte at time */
    void *shmem_ptr60;
    int shmem60;
    char *shmem_char;
    size = sizeof(char) * PLENGHT;   /* shared m. data size (size was already declared )*/

    /* getting shared m. id */
    if ( (shmem60 =  shmget(3333, size , 0666 | IPC_CREAT )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer */
    if ((shmem_ptr60 = shmat(shmem60, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error");

    shmem_char = shmem_ptr60;

    /* locking mutex before creating new process to avoid child reading void memory area */
    if( (mu_err = pthread_mutex_lock(mu)) != 0 ) err_exit(mu_err,"lock mutex error");

    /* calling child */
    pid_t pid;
    if( (pid = vfork()) == -1 )err_sys("fork error");
    else if(pid == 0){
        if (execl("./test2","test2",(void*)0) == -1) err_sys("exec error");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid == -1 ) err_sys("fork error");


    /*  copying data inside shared memory */
    for( int i = 0; i < PNUM; i++){
        strcpy(shmem_char, packet);
        printf("data written, iteration number :%d\n",i);
        if ( (mu_err = pthread_cond_signal(cond)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"cond signal error: ");
        if ( (mu_err = pthread_cond_wait(cond, mu)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"cond wait error"); 
    }
    if ( (mu_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(mu)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"mutex unlock error");

    waitpid(pid,NULL,(int)NULL);

    if (shmctl(shmem_mu_id, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0) err_sys("shmctl error");
    if (shmctl(shmem_cond_id, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0) err_sys("shmctl error");
    if (shmctl(shmem60, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0) err_sys("shmctl error");

    return 0;
}


/* from apue to print errors*/
void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, errno, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, error, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap){
    char    buf[MAXLINE];

    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE-1, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf)-1, ": %s",
          strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */
}
```

#### File `test2.c`

Then, child recovers all shared memory areas containing mutex, condition variable and data, and try to read. Code below is the child.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h> 

#define PNUM 17500  
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define PLENGHT 60


void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...);
void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...);
static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap);



int main (int argc , char *argv[]){
    char packets[PNUM][PLENGHT];


    /* -----recovering mutex inside shared memory */
    pthread_mutex_t *mu;
    int shmem_mu_id;
    void* shmem_mu_ptr;
    int mu_err;

    /* getting shared m. id for data*/
    if ( (shmem_mu_id =  shmget((key_t)1111, 0 , 0666 | IPC_CREAT )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for data */
    if ((shmem_mu_ptr = shmat(shmem_mu_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make mu, that expects a memory area made like pthread_mutex_t *, to point the shared memory. */
    mu = (pthread_mutex_t *)shmem_mu_ptr;


    /* -----recovering condition variable inside shared memory */
    void *shmem_cond_ptr;           /* pointer to cond shared memory */
    int shmem_cond_id;              /* shared memory cond id */     
    pthread_cond_t *cond;

    /* getting shared m. id for cond*/
    if ( (shmem_cond_id =  shmget((key_t)2222, 0 , 0666 | IPC_CREAT )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for cond */
    if ((shmem_cond_ptr = shmat(shmem_cond_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make cond, that expects a memory area made like pthread_cond_t , to point the shared memory. */
    cond = (pthread_cond_t *)shmem_cond_ptr;

    /* recovering shared memory aread with data */
    int shmem;
    char *shmem_ptr;

    if ( (shmem =  shmget(3333, 0, 0666 )) == -1) err_sys("shared memory error ");
    if ((shmem_ptr = shmat(shmem, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1) err_sys("shmat error child");


    if( (mu_err = pthread_mutex_lock(mu)) != 0 ) err_exit(mu_err,"lock mutex error");

    /* try to read data inside shared memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < PNUM; i++){ 
        strcpy(packets[i],shmem_ptr);
        printf("data read, iteration number :%d\n",i);
        if ( (mu_err = pthread_cond_signal(cond)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"cond signal error: ");
        if ( (mu_err = pthread_cond_wait(cond, mu)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"cond wait error"); 

    }

    if ( (mu_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(mu)) != 0) err_exit(mu_err,"mutex unlock error");
    return 0;

}




/* from apue to print errors*/
void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, errno, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...){
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, error, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap){
    char    buf[MAXLINE];

    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE-1, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf)-1, ": %s",
          strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */
}
```

The problem appears inside the for loop in the parent: pthread_cond_wait after a random numbers of iterations fail with invalid argument error.

This is the output:

```
[...]
data written, iteration number :85
data read, iteration number :85
data written, iteration number :86
data read, iteration number :86
data written, iteration number :87
data read, iteration number :87
data written, iteration number :88
data read, iteration number :88
data written, iteration number :89
data read, iteration number :89
data written, iteration number :90
data read, iteration number :90
cond wait error: Invalid argument
```

The `pthread_cond_wait` function man page says:

> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition 
>   variable cond; atomically here means "atomically with respect to access by another thread
>   to the mutex and then the condition variable".

I'm working with processes, not with threads: can this explain the issue or did I make an error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  I know it's hard, but we like to see an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).
It's important because it is hard for us to test your code if we have to write swathes of test harness to get it to compile and run — and there's no guarantee we'll make the same mistakes as you do. As a "for instance", it is not clear what the type or role of the `size` variable is.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Jonathan, sorry but I'm new here! I've modified my question to make both parent and child simply verifiable. I hope it goes well.

Comment: When I compile the server code (GCC 9.2.0 on a MacBook Pro), I get: `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]` —
  `115 |     waitpid(pid,NULL,(int)NULL);`.  Use `0` when you mean `0`.  Don't cast `NULL` — especially not to a non-pointer type.

Comment: Ok I will. I've compiled with Clang 11.0.0 on a MacBook Air and i didn't receive any warnings.

Comment: My GCC 9.2.0 is a compiler I compiled, not the Apple-provided version.  GCC and Clang do sometimes warn about different things.  I had to apply `-Wno-expansion-to-defined` to avoid errors from `pthread.h`.  I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.3 on this Mac, with Xcode 11.3.1 installed.  My default warnings also tell me that `int main(int argc, char **argv)` should be `int main(void)` since you don't use the command-line arguments.

Comment: It can't be good double-destroying the condition attribute: `/* Initialize condition. */
    pthread_cond_init(cond, &attrcond);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);

    /* Clean up. */
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);`.  More generally, you should error check every pthread call.

Comment: I wouldn't use `vfork()`.  In the `test1.c` code, you have two tests for the same `vfork()` error; the second is superfluous since it will never be executed.

Comment: The double instruction:  `thread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond)` and the double check on `vfork()` are distracting errors, it was not my intention to write them. I've also added the check to every pthread call.
Thanks for corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is bug in Macos when conditional variable lives in shared memory and this cond variable may hold pointer to mutex. As shmat() might return random addresses for each of the processes, thus at some point cond variable internals might hold the pointer to "logically" the same Mutex, but with different address, due to shmat() logic. Thus these different addresses confuses the pthread_cond_wait() and it returns EINVAL.

I was fighting with this for when working on Enduro/X middleware. Basically was also getting random errors when different processes used shared cond variable.

The solution was to hack the Macos Opaque type pthread_cond_t (extract header infos from the Darwin phtreads library) and reset the cond variable internals to get it more or less functional at pthread_cond_wait() entry.

The sources for working solution (wrappers) are here: https://github.com/endurox-dev/endurox/blob/master/libnstd/sys_emqueue.c, Also some additional research notes here: https://www.endurox.org/issues/512

To get explanation for the error, take a look on Darwin source:

https://github.com/apple/darwin-libpthread/blob/main/src/pthread_cond.c

```
int _pthread_cond_wait(pthread_cond_t *cond, pthread_mutex_t *mutex,
        const struct timespec *abstime, int isRelative,
        pthread_conformance_t conforming)
...
if (!ulock && cond->busy != NULL && cond->busy != mutex) { //<<< Here it compares your mutex ptr with some "busy" field. "busy" is set elsewhere by other process. And it would be set to other process mutex pointer. Thus pointer might, even the other process is using logically the same mutex as for normal pthread_cond_wait() application.
    // TODO: PTHREAD_STRICT candidate
    return EINVAL;
}
```

Where the "busy" field at some stage is set in _pthread_psynch_cond_wait() when firstly it did pass these filter.

Thus solution is to reset the internal busy field to NULL and let _pthread_psynch_cond_wait() do the actual wait logic. As it seems that _pthread_cond_wait() is more or less just some entry wrapper/checker.

To get access to the internals of the pthread_cond_t, I used the snippet:

```
enter code here

typedef struct {
    long sig;
    uint32_t lock;
    uint32_t unused;
    char *busy;
} ndrx_osx_pthread_cond_t;
```

Then just prior the pthread_cond_wait() entry, cast the cond variable to ndrx_osx_pthread_cond_t and reset the busy to NULL.
Also due to fact the several processes might set the busy field back to some invalid value, my solution was to do it with several attempts.

All this above works with Macos 10, not sure about Macos 11, did not yet get the access to the machine :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an unconstrained buffer overflow because you don't null terminate a string.  You have:

```
char packet[PLENGHT];

for(int i = 0; i < PLENGHT; i++) packet[i] = 'a';

…lots of lines…

strcpy(shmem_char, packet);
```

Copying a non-string with `strcpy()` is not a good idea — you have a buffer overflow.  I added:

```
packet[PLENGHT - 1] = '\0';
```

and things seemed to work.

I added some diagnostic information and got to:

```
data written, iteration number :17499
data read, iteration number: 17499 [aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
```

Then the programs hung — I had to interrupt them.

Note that `PLENGTH` would be the more normal spelling for a length.

#### Revised code `test1.c`

I've reduced the number of iterations to 25 (from 17500).  I've fixed various things, and chose to use my own error reporting code, which is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  I needed to know which program was generating the error; I got the information (it was `test1`) using these functions.  I didn't spend the time retrofitting the code into `test2.c`.  I've added an extra `pthread_cond_signal()` after the main loop in `test1.c`; now the child exits, so the parent exits — and all is orderly.  All the `pthread_*` calls are error checked.  The code modifies the message before it is sent so you can tell whether the child is picking up the correct message.  The message is printed before it is sent, and after it is read.

The primary bug fix is adding;

```
    packet[PLENGTH - 1] = '\0';
```

That ensures the packet contains a string, not just a buffer full of bytes.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

//#define PNUM 17500
#define PNUM 25
#define PLENGTH 60
#define MAXLINE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 0)
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    /* creating new mutex inside shared memory area */
    void *shmem_mu_ptr;             /* pointer to mutex shared memory */
    pthread_mutex_t *mu;            /* pointer to mutex */
    int shmem_mu_id;                /* shared memory mutex id */
    int mu_err;
    size_t size = sizeof(pthread_mutex_t);  /* shared m. mutex size (size was already declared) */
    char packet[PLENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; i < PLENGTH; i++)
        packet[i] = 'a';
    packet[PLENGTH - 1] = '\0';

    /* getting shared m. id for mutex*/
    if ((shmem_mu_id =  shmget((key_t)1111, size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        err_syserr("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for mutex */
    if ((shmem_mu_ptr = shmat(shmem_mu_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_syserr("shmat error: ");

    /* make mu, that expects a memory area made like pthread_mutex_t , to point the shared memory. */
    mu = (pthread_mutex_t *)shmem_mu_ptr;

    /* initialize the attribute to prepare mutex to be placed in shared memory */
    int rc;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
    if ((rc = pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_mutexattr_init: ");
    if ((rc = pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_mutexattr_setpshared: ");

    /* initialize mutex */
    if ((rc = pthread_mutex_init(mu, &attr)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_mutex_init: ");
    if ((rc = pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_mutexattr_destroy: ");

    /* creating new condition variable inside shared memory area */
    void *shmem_cond_ptr;           /* pointer to cond shared memory */
    int shmem_cond_id;              /* shared memory cond id */
    pthread_cond_t *cond;
    size = sizeof(pthread_cond_t);  /* shared m. cond size (size was already declared) */

    /* getting shared m. id for cond*/
    if ((shmem_cond_id =  shmget((key_t)2222, size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        err_syserr("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for cond */
    if ((shmem_cond_ptr = shmat(shmem_cond_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_syserr("shmat error: ");

    /* make cond, that expects a memory area made like pthread_cond_t , to point the shared memory. */
    cond = (pthread_cond_t *)shmem_cond_ptr;

    /* * initialize the attribute to prepare cond to be placed in shared memory */
    pthread_condattr_t attrcond;
    if ((rc = pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_condattr_init: ");
    if ((rc = pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_condattr_setpshared: ");

    /* Initialize condition. */
    if ((rc = pthread_cond_init(cond, &attrcond)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_cond_init: ");
    if ((rc = pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond)) != 0)
        err_syserror(rc, "pthread_condattr_destroy: ");

    /* Clean up. */
    //pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);

    /* creating new shared memory area to share only PLENGTH (60) byte at time */
    void *shmem_ptr60;
    int shmem60;
    char *shmem_char;
    size = sizeof(char) * PLENGTH;   /* shared m. data size (size was already declared) */

    /* getting shared m. id */
    if ((shmem60 = shmget(3333, size, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        err_syserr("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer */
    if ((shmem_ptr60 = shmat(shmem60, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_syserr("shmat error: ");

    shmem_char = shmem_ptr60;

    /* locking mutex before creating new process to avoid child reading void memory area */
    if ((mu_err = pthread_mutex_lock(mu)) != 0)
        err_syserror(mu_err, "lock mutex error: ");

    /* calling child */
    pid_t pid;
    //if ((pid = vfork()) == -1)
    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        err_syserr("fork error: ");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execl("./test2", "test2", (void *)0) == -1)
            err_syserr("exec error: ");
        exit(0);
    }
    //else if (pid == -1)
        //err_syserr("fork error: ");
    printf("Child forked OK\n");

    /*  copying data inside shared memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < PNUM; i++)
    {
        packet[i % (PLENGTH - 1)]++;
        strcpy(shmem_char, packet);
        printf("data written, iteration number: %d [%s]\n", i, packet);
        if ((mu_err = pthread_cond_signal(cond)) != 0)
            err_syserror(mu_err, "pthread_cond_signal: ");
        if ((mu_err = pthread_cond_wait(cond, mu)) != 0)
            err_syserror(mu_err, "pthread_cond_wait: ");
    }
    if ((mu_err = pthread_cond_signal(cond)) != 0)
        err_syserror(mu_err, "pthread_cond_signal: ");
    if ((mu_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(mu)) != 0)
        err_syserror(mu_err, "pthread_mutex_unlock: ");

    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    if (shmctl(shmem_mu_id, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0)
        err_syserr("shmctl error: ");
    if (shmctl(shmem_cond_id, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0)
        err_syserr("shmctl error: ");
    if (shmctl(shmem60, IPC_RMID, 0) < 0)
        err_syserr("shmctl error: ");

    return 0;
}
```

#### Revised code `test2.c`

This is generally much less heavily edited.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

//#define PNUM 17500
#define PNUM 25
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define PLENGTH 60

void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...);
void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...);
static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap);

int main(void)
{
    char packets[PNUM][PLENGTH];

    /* -----recovering mutex inside shared memory */
    pthread_mutex_t *mu;
    int shmem_mu_id;
    void *shmem_mu_ptr;
    int mu_err;

    /* getting shared m. id for data*/
    if ((shmem_mu_id =  shmget((key_t)1111, 0, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for data */
    if ((shmem_mu_ptr = shmat(shmem_mu_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make mu, that expects a memory area made like pthread_mutex_t *, to point the shared memory. */
    mu = (pthread_mutex_t *)shmem_mu_ptr;

    printf("mutex recovered\n");

    /* -----recovering condition variable inside shared memory */
    void *shmem_cond_ptr;           /* pointer to cond shared memory */
    int shmem_cond_id;              /* shared memory cond id */
    pthread_cond_t *cond;

    /* getting shared m. id for cond*/
    if ((shmem_cond_id =  shmget((key_t)2222, 0, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1)
        err_sys("shared memory error ");

    /* getting shared m. pointer for cond */
    if ((shmem_cond_ptr = shmat(shmem_cond_id, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_sys("shmat error");

    /* make cond, that expects a memory area made like pthread_cond_t , to point the shared memory. */
    cond = (pthread_cond_t *)shmem_cond_ptr;
    printf("condition recovered\n");

    /* recovering shared memory read with data */
    int shmem;
    char *shmem_ptr;

    if ((shmem = shmget(3333, 0, 0666)) == -1)
        err_sys("shared memory error ");
    if ((shmem_ptr = shmat(shmem, 0, 0)) == (void *)-1)
        err_sys("shmat error child");
    printf("data memory recovered\n");

    if ((mu_err = pthread_mutex_lock(mu)) != 0)
        err_exit(mu_err, "lock mutex error");

    /* try to read data inside shared memory */
    for (int i = 0; i < PNUM; i++)
    {
        strcpy(packets[i], shmem_ptr);
        printf("data read, iteration number: %d [%s]\n", i, packets[i]);
        if ((mu_err = pthread_cond_signal(cond)) != 0)
            err_exit(mu_err, "cond signal error: ");
        if ((mu_err = pthread_cond_wait(cond, mu)) != 0)
            err_exit(mu_err, "cond wait error");
    }

    if ((mu_err = pthread_mutex_unlock(mu)) != 0)
        err_exit(mu_err, "mutex unlock error");
    return 0;
}

/* from apue to print errors*/
void err_sys(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, errno, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

void err_exit(int error, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(1, error, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    exit(1);
}

static void err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char buf[MAXLINE];

    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE - 1, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf + strlen(buf), MAXLINE - strlen(buf) - 1, ": %s",
                 strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ ./test1
Child forked OK
data written, iteration number: 0 [baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
mutex recovered
condition recovered
data memory recovered
data read, iteration number: 0 [baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 1 [bbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 1 [bbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 2 [bbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 2 [bbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 3 [bbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 3 [bbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 4 [bbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 4 [bbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 5 [bbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 5 [bbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 6 [bbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 6 [bbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 7 [bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 7 [bbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 8 [bbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 8 [bbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 9 [bbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 9 [bbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 10 [bbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 10 [bbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 11 [bbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 11 [bbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 12 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 12 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 13 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 13 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 14 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 14 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 15 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 15 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 16 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 16 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 17 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 17 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 18 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 18 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 19 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 19 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 20 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 20 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 21 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 21 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 22 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 22 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 23 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 23 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data written, iteration number: 24 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
data read, iteration number: 24 [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa]
$
```

#### Test environment

I'm running a MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina 10.15.3 and using GCC 9.2.0 (which I compiled myself) and Xcode 11.3.1 for anything that's not formally a part of GCC.

Curious observation: I don't seem to have a man page for `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()` or `pthread_condattr_setpshared()`, but both functions are found when linking (and compiling) and seem to work OK.

Comment: I suspect that the child is waiting for a `pthread_cond_signal()` that never arrives, so it doesn't terminate the loop and exit, so the parent is stuck waiting for the child to exit — deadlock.

Comment: I've added the line `packet[PLENGHT - 1] = '\0'; ` after `for(int i = 0; i < PLENGHT; i++) packet[i] = 'a';`  but on my pc I continue having the error  `invalid argument` after some iterations.

Comment: @Pali — That's curious.  Try copying the code from my answer (you'll need to get the files from my SOQ GitHub repository too) and compile that.  Keep your own versions, of course.  What's your environment?  MacBook Air running macOS?  Which version?

Comment: I'm running on macOS Catalina 10.15.3, Xcode 11.3.1 and clang 11.0.0 . After the corrections, I compiled and executed the same code that on my MacBook Air continue to cause the error on a Linux pc (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and GCC 7.4.0), and... works. No errors occur on `pthread_cond_wait()`. Like you, in the end, I had a deadlock that, like you, i had easily fixed simply adding an `pthread_cond_signal()` after the main loop in test1.c,  Now I will try to compile and execute the code you posted and I will let you know if works on my MacBook Air

Comment: I don't have the man page for `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()` too, but I used online man [http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html] (since there was no page I just assumed)

Comment: When I set the repeat count big enough (back to 17500), I start getting some weird effects.  The value of `i` in `test2.c` gets intermittently corrupted, usually with a 5-digit number.  The point at which the failure occurs is erratic.  The 'modify packet' code above isn't safe.  I'm now using: `int j = i % (PLENGTH - 1);` — `if (++packet[j] > 'z')` — `packet[j] = 'a';` – `strcpy(shmem_char, packet);`.  But something still goes wrong.  I'm getting the failure on `pthread_cond_wait()` with `EINVAL` from both `test1` and `test2`, which is a little surprising. Occasionally, it even exits cleanly.

Comment: I compile and execute your code and i continue getting the failure on `pthread_cond_wait()` with `EINVAL` .